# Verificar se data está entre um período

Tags: sql, sql-server

Na minha tabela, tenho duas colunas, `DT_INICIO` e `DT_FIM`, seria uma tabela de Ausência.

Vamos supor que um funcionário está Ausente na `DT_INICIO` De (25/03/2016) Até `DT_FIM` (27/03/2016), eu preciso fazer uma consulta na data 26/03/2016, como eu verifico se essa data está entre Inicio e Fim?

Obrigado.

Comment: `Data > DT_INICIO AND Data < DT_FIM`? Dá pra usar também `BETWEEN`

Comment: Você pode usar `...where data between data_inicio and data_fim` ou  `...where  data >= data_inicio and data  <= data_fim`, simples assim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o  [between](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187922(v=sql.120).aspx) ele especifica um intervalo a ser testado.

Sintaxe:

```
test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

Argumentos?

*test_expression*

> É a expressão a ser testada no intervalo definido por
>   begin_expressione end_expression. test_expression deve ter o mesmo
>   tipo de dados que begin_expression e end_expression.

*NOT*

> Especifica que o resultado do predicado deve ser negado.

*begin_expression*

> É qualquer expressão válida. begin_expression deve ter o mesmo tipo de
>   dados que test_expression e end_expression.

*end_expression*

> É qualquer expressão válida. end_expression deve ter o mesmo tipo de
>   dados que test_expressione begin_expression.

*AND*

> Atua como um espaço reservado que indica que test_expression deve
>   estar dentro do intervalo indicado por begin_expression e
>   end_expression.

Resumindo.

```
Select * from sua tabela
where suadata BETWEEN DT_INICIO and DT_FIM
```

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado